# How to overcome SVN -- could not open the requested SVN file system

Tags: svn, apache-http-server

I followed all the steps in https://help.ubuntu.com/8.04/serverguide/C/subversion.html
but when I try to do:

```
svn co https://localhost/svn
```

I get:

```
 svn: Repository moved permanently to 'https://localhost/svn/'
```

...and when I do:

```
 svn co https://localhost/svn/
```

I get the same error again.  When I try:

```
 svn co https://localhost/svn/testrepo
```

I get:

```
 svn: Could not open the requested SVN filesystem
```

In apache logs I see:

```
 can't open file /home/myname/testrepo/testrepo/format
```

In my apache2.conf I have:

```
<Location /svn>
     DAV svn
     SVNParentPath /home/myname/testrepo
     SVNListParentPath On
     AuthType Basic
     AuthName "myrepo"
     AuthUserFile /etc/subversion/passwd
     <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
         Require valid-user
     <LimitExcept>
</Location>
```

I also tried previously with "SVNPath" instead of "parentpath" without success.

Please help, I'm desperate!!  I tried all combination of paths I could think of...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems as SVNParentPath is pointing directly to your repository, rather than to a directory that contains your repository.

Create a folder called **projects** in your home folder

```
mkdir /home/myname/projects
```

Move your repository into **projects**.

```
mv /home/myname/testrepo /home/myname/projects
```

Change the ownership of **projects** to www-data.

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /home/myname/projects
```

In apache2.conf, change your declaration of SVNParentPath to

```
SVNParentPath /home/myname/projects
```

Restart your Apache server.

Now try checking out your repository.

```
svn co https://localhost/svn/testrepo
```

Comment: i dont understand how this worked because for me when i do SVNParentPath /home/myname/projects. and restart the apache server, i get an error saying "syntax error on apache2.conf" same line where i added "SVNParentPath /home/myname/projects"

Comment: @jonney Is Correct, adding that line to the apache2.conf causes that error

Comment: In my case, it turns out I made a mistake in the ./apache2/mods-enabled/dav_svn.conf file and trying to use my actual project location not the parent folder (up one dir ../<project>), in my case: "/storage/data/svn-database/" with my project being "/storage/data/svn-database/TestProject", I had to make sure my SVNParentPath in that file was set to the location of "ALL" the projects ./svn-database/ not the project ./TestProject ; After Correction and Restarting Apache, Project Finally works

Answer (score 1):

For Windows users (if someone has a similar problem under Windows):

The problem could be file access permissions.

I solved my problem by moving the repository to the location where Apache can read and write the files. In my case (CollabNet Subversion Edge) the path was `C:\csvn\data\repositories`.

Answer (score 0):

Go to SVNParentPath Directory Here my directory path is /var/www/svn

**cd /var/www/svn/**

Create a Repository Under SVNParentPath

**svnadmin create repo_name**

Give Apache Permission

**chown -R apache:apache repo_name/**

Create a SVN User

**htpasswd -m /etc/httpd/conf/.htpasswd username**

Assign Permission

**vi /etc/svnusers
[repo_name:/]**

username=rw

Restart Apache Service

**service httpd restart**